# Array representation in scheme

Tags: scheme

I am a newbie to the realm of functional programming and have just started learning Scheme (though it is a semi-functional programming language). I did some tutorials on lists which is well supported in Scheme. I was wondering whether Scheme has support for fiddling with arrays ?

Or do I need to define my own data type ? Lists are an inductively defined data types. If I'm to define arrays as a new data type then can it be defined inductively ?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for [vector](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Vectors.html).

```
(define arr (vector 1 2 3))
(define arr '#(1 2 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the notion of vector in scheme. I just looked up for it and it seems, one can do a look up in constant time (just like in arrays). Also, it seems to be a data type fixed in space - much like an array.

cheers

Comment: Remember that vector constants (in R5RS at least) must be quoted. The last example should be `(define arr '#(1 2 3))`. Note: some implementations make the quote optional.

Answer (score 2):

you can represent arrays using vectors. The vectors in Scheme are not functional in the sense that you can mutate them (using vector-set!). However, also lists *can* be mutated using set-car! and set-cdr!.